# Apply Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> in Generic Repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

Currently, I have a Generic repository like this:

```
    public virtual IQueryFluent<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query)
    {
        return new QueryFluent<TEntity>(this, query);
    }
```

And implement like this:

```
    var obj = _repository.Query(x => x.RoleID == ID).Select().FirstOrDefault();
```

Because, RoleID appears in all entities, so that I want to build an Expression common in the Generic Repository like this:

```
    //Check and get RoleID if exist this column
    PropertyInfo info = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("RoleID");
    if (info != null) 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = (p => p.RoleID ??? or p.info ??? == 5);
```

How could we build a filter with unknown column from TEntity in Generic Repository? Or could we pass a string of where clause for Filter?

My purpose is that, I just need query data with simple structure like that:

```
    var obj = _repository.Query().Select().FirstOrDefault();
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Best would be to implement some interface like `IHasRole {int RoleID{get;set;}}` on all entities and use that.

Comment: thank Evk for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify those entities with RoleID using an interface, like:

```
interface IEntity { }
interface IRoleIdentifiedEntity : IEntity
{
    int RoleID { get; }
}
```

For all entities, use the generic repository:

```
class GenericRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For entities with `IRoleIdentifiedEntity`, use another repository:

```
class RoleIdentifiedRepositoryBase<T> : GenericRepository<T>
    where T : IRoleIdentifiedEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Query(int id)
    {
        return Query(e => e.RoleID == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Danny Chen, 
My RoleID was created by .edmx, it is a column of table from SQL. Could we use reflector to get property info and work on this?

Comment: @Langthang it's not a problem, because classes generated from .edmx are partial, so you can extend them with interface without modifying autogenerated files.

Comment: @Langthang Reflection won't help in this case. As Evk said, you can use partial class.

Comment: thanks Danny and Evk much, I will try to apply your approach.